# sshpass No such file or directory

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, sshpass

need add string to file on remote ssh server without prompting sudo password

myuser=testuser

```
$ sshpass -p "$mypass" ssh -t -o StrictHostKeycheking=no $myuser@$myhost "echo $mypass | sudo -S -s /bin/bash -c \"echo $myText >> test.txt\""
```

sometimes it gives me

```
[sudo] password for testuser: /bin/bash: line 1: test.txt: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Why do you need sudo? Don't you have write access to your home directory? Anyways, you might try with `sudo tee test.txt <<< "$myText"` or write to `/tmp` and `sudo mv` to the final destination. You should review your workflow, this is a security nightmare.

Comment: it's not my server.  test.txt file path is different for example /root/test.txt